# Using sigaction with or without sigsetjmp

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

I have an exercise for which I have to implement a function that takes as parameters a one-parameter function pointer `fun`, a parameter to the function pointed at by said pointer `parameter` and an integer `period`. This function will return either 1 in case the execution of the function `fun` points to with `parameter` as parameter terminates before `period` seconds, or 0 if not.

Are these two solutions equivalent?

```
static struct sigaction sa, old;
static jmp_buf env;

static void myalarm(int sig)
{
  printf("alarm!\n");
  siglongjmp(env,1);
}

int execution_time_limit( void (*fun)(void *), void *parameter, int period)
{
  sa.sa_handler = myalarm;
  sa.sa_flags = 0; 
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, &old);

  alarm(period);
  if(sigsetjmp(env,1) == 0) {
    fun(parameter);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &old, NULL);
  }
  else
    return 0;
 return 1;
}
```

And:

```
static struct sigaction sa, old;
static jmp_buf env;
int ret = 0;

static void myalarm(int sig)
{
  printf("alarm!\n");
  ret = 1;
}

int execution_time_limit( void (*fun)(void *), void *parameter, int period)
{
  sa.sa_handler = myalarm;
  sa.sa_flags = 0; 
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, &old);

  alarm(period);
  fun(parameter);
  sigaction(SIGALRM, &old, NULL);
  return ret;
}
```

I'd say yes, but I'd like to clear up any doubt I might have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not the same.

In the first example, if the alarm is triggered, `fun` does not exit normally due to the call to `siglongjmp`.  In the second example, the alarm will set the flag for the return value, but `fun` will continue to run to completion.

Also, you have a bug here:

```
  if(sigsetjmp(env,1) == 0) 
    fun(parameter);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &old, NULL);
  else
    return 0
  return 1;
```

You're missing braces around the `if` and `else` blocks, and missing the `;` after the first `return`.  Also I believe you have the return values mixed up based on your description of what the function should do.

The fixed code:

```
  if(sigsetjmp(env,1) == 0) {
    fun(parameter);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &old, NULL);
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
```

Comment: You are right, I got the return values mixed up (fixed that). And yes it is obvious that `fun` will run to completion with the second code, unlike with the first. But the end result is the same, isn't it?

Comment: @WIlopu If by "end result is the same" you mean "does `execution_time_limit` return the value you expect in both cases" then yes.  However, in the second case, if you set `period` to 5 but `fun` takes 60 seconds to run, then `execution_time_limit` won't return until the 60 seconds is done.  If you want `execution_time_limit` to run no longer than `period`, use the second method.

Comment: That what I figured, it is nice to have confirmation. Thank you.

Comment: Further bugs.  The first example will leave SIGALRM set to `myalarm` if we long jump.  ([SA_RESETHAND](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sigaction.html) would avoid this.)  Neither example turns off the alarm if `fun` completes in time — I hope the rest of the code is ready for a long jump or EINTR!  Finally, `alarm` is inherently race-prone in uses like this, even if we attempt to disable before the timeout.  For the OP's purposes, it'd be easier just to time `fun`'s execution and avoid signals completely.